# 403 response when trying to pull Youtube content owner reports using Reporting API

Tags: youtube, youtube-analytics-api

I have been granted 'owner' rights to a YouTube content owner account and I have created oauth credentials for the account trying to access content owner reports with all the scopes described here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/content_owner_reports

However, when I run the bulk report method `reportTypes.list` to try to see what content owner reports are available, I am always getting 403 (forbidden - The caller does not have permission) responses back. I got the same response using the analytics API by setting the `contentOwner` parameter.

Is there anything I will need to configure in the content owner account or in my account (as an owner of the content owner account) in order to be able to see the list of content owner reports? Or does my account need to be a channel account in order to view the content owner report?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may not be part of the partner program (within the link you posted):

`Note: Content owner reports are only accessible to YouTube content partners who participate in the YouTube Partner Program.`